# How do I control the clicks of a browse button?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a browse button, and two empty images (image1, image2). I want to first click the browse button and load an image to (image1). On the second click I want to load the image to (image2).

I'm very new to WPF and C# in general. I guess I need some method to control the clicks of the button? Does anyone have any idea about this? I would highly appreciate it.

This is my code behind attempt:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog fd = new OpenFileDialog();
        fd.DefaultExt = ".tif";
        fd.Filter = "(*.tif,*.tiff)|*.tif;*.tiff";
        fd.ShowDialog();
        string fname = fd.FileName;
        textBox1.Text = fname;

        image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(fd.FileName));
    }
```

After this, the first image is displayed in image1, but when I browse for another image it comes on top of image 1, and not in image2. How can I make the second image that I browse display in image2? maybe something like, if the button is already clicked one time, then the image should load into image2? or if image1 is already full then load to image2? I'm not sure!

Oh and the purpose of this is to create an interface that lets the user browse different images shown in a listbox, and when the user clicks each image, it displays in another window and the user can zoom in and out and so on.

But right now I'm just stuck with this small part of my project!

Comment: I didn't get the exact purpose. perhaps you can keep a flag in the code and check and update it every time browse is clicked to set and detect the count of click.

Comment: Show your code attempt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I question the why you want to do such a thing, you could use the following. Also, please show some effort next time. This is a relatively easy solution!

```
private bool _ImageOneSet;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _ImageOneSet = false;
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!_ImageOneSet)
    {
        // set image one
        _ImageOneSet = true;
    }
    else
    {
        // set image two
    }       
}
```

I use a private field that is set to false. The first time the button_click event gets triggered, `_ImageOneSet` is still `false`, so you can set the first image.

The second (and third, fourth etc...), `_ImageOneSet` is `true` so you will set the second image.